# I need to get coulmn wise duplicate count using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

[image: 1]

I have data as shown in the table I need to get the count of column-wise duplicates using ReactJs.

Comment: not exactly sure what you want. if you ask total row count for each column then every count will be same. can you please clarify your question?

Comment: my expected output is in the Name coulmn john count is 4 and in the same column mary count is 2 like this i need to get for each column how many duplicates are there

Comment: What the input look like ?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please check the **below example.** I used `material-ui`. I attached output screen too

[image]

**Here is the working example**

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableContainer from '@material-ui/core/TableContainer';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';

function createRow(id, name, city, dateofbirth, school, klass) {
    return {id, name, city, dateofbirth, school, klass};
}

function showNameCount(data) {
    let unique = data.map(item => item.name).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index);

    let divs = [];
    unique.map(u => {
        divs.push(<div>{u}: {data.filter(d => d.name === u).length}</div>);
    });
    return divs;
}

const rows = [
    createRow(1, 'John', 'newyork', '15-Aug-98', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(2, 'Mary', 'chicago', '28-Jun-97', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(3, 'John', 'newyork', '12-May-98', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(4, 'Hary', 'chicago', '15-Aug-98', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(5, 'Mary', 'newyork', '28-Jun-97', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(6, 'John', 'newyork', '12-May-98', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(7, 'Hary', 'newyork', '15-Aug-98', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(8, 'Stella', 'chicago', '28-Jun-97', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(9, 'John', 'newyork', '12-May-98', 'newyork university', 'degree'),
    createRow(10, 'Stella', 'chicago', '12-May-98', 'newyork university', 'degree')
];

export default function TableWithFooter() {
    return (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
            <Table aria-label="spanning table">
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Id</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Name</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>City</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Date of Birth</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>School</TableCell>
                        <TableCell>Class</TableCell>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>
                    {rows.map((row) => (
                        <TableRow key={row.id}>
                            <TableCell>{row.id}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{row.name}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{row.city}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{row.dateofbirth}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{row.school}</TableCell>
                            <TableCell>{row.klass}</TableCell>
                        </TableRow>
                    ))}
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell/>
                        <TableCell>
                            {
                                showNameCount(rows)
                            }
                        </TableCell>
                        <TableCell rowSpan={4}/>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableBody>
            </Table>
        </TableContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Khabir, But how can I do for multiple column here working with one column is ok but i want duplicate data in every column like in city ,dateofBirth,school ,klass how i can iterate through each column